# CoreData NSManagedObject isn't being updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, updates

I'm trying to update an existing object in my Core Data stack, 
The object is being retrieved and i can change the value, but when saving the context , nothing is being saved. also the `hasChanges` is NO and `updatedObjects` is empty.

```cpp
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"MyModel"];
NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(x == %@) AND (y == %@)", x, y];

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
request.predicate       = predicate;

NSArray *results        = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: request error: nil];
MyModel *model          = results[0];

model.newvalue          = "somenewvalue";

NSLog(@"%@", (self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges)?@"YES":@"NO"); // -> Shows NO
NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectContext.updatedObjects); // -> Shows empty array

[self saveContext]; // No error, seems to be working successfully but the updated objects is empty as well has "hasChanges", so something else is being missed here
```

This is a bit baffling and annoying. I would really appreciate any insights on this issue.

As suggested this was tried as well but didn't help

```
NSManagedObject *model  = results[0];
[model setValue: @"somenewvalue" forKey: @"newvalue"];
```

Comment: results.newvalue does not make sense and would not compile. Did you mean model.newvalue ?

Comment: Hey man, that's just a typo when I wrote down the example. In my actual source code its written correctly. Fixed.

Comment: Is `results` nil ? Does `executeFetchRequest` give an error ?

Comment: Hey @Wain , As i wrote in the description, the object is being retreieved correctly without any issues or errors. The only issue is it seems the Managed Object Context doesn't seem to realize the object was modified.

Comment: For testing purposes, is it possible to bypass the NSManagedObject subclass MyModel and use KVC to set the attribute? That is, use setValue:forKey: to modify whatever attribute is wrapped by the newvalue property. If that works, then there might be something wrong with MyModel.

Comment: I can't for legal reasons :) But its exactly the same except for changing the names of same Objects. I've tried what you offered and that doesn't work as well. I'm editing the question to show the extra attempt.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about KVC, I think it just calls the setter for the property (if one exists), so that's a bad test unless you also comment out the corresponding property in MyModel.

Comment: what is the value of `newvalue` before the update? (if it is "somevalue" no changes will be registered).

Comment: @DanShelly: In my experience, even setting the existing value of a managed object again marks the context as "hasChanges".

Comment: @DanShelly - The value is different then what I change it to, it just doesn't register it as a change

Comment: @MartinR: True, the context does register the object, even for the same value. however, the object itself does not register any changed values ==> will not help in this case. This obviously does not reproduce in my env. was the context accessed by any other thread (reset, saved)?

Comment: It is saved in the beginning of my session, and then I perform the fetch, update and try to save...

Comment: @ShaiMishali Have you overridden the `setNewvalue:` property? whet is you implementation for `self.managedObjectContext`? what do you mean by "session"? does `model` register any changes? (the code as describe should register a change in the context, so the problem must lie elsewhere)

Comment: I have not overridden it. And here's the implementation (from stock apple template): http://pastebin.com/DQGxFBGb. Model does register the changes but the Managed Context isn't recognizing them.

Comment: Can you log: `self.managedObjectContext` and `model.managedObjectContext`?

Comment: @DanShelly - Right now i'm just making a copy of the old record, modifying it - deleting the old and inserting the new. That works. but a simple update doesn't. I'm gonna try having a version of my code running with MagicalRecord and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crazy answer but I can definitely imagine someone else making this error.
Inside my NSManagedObject instead of ***@dynamic*** for each property I had ***@synthesize***. That was the issue.